# How can I get a list of test users with Facebook API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Reading https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/ , I do not see an API call to get a list of test users.

How can I get it then? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[APP_ID]/accounts/test-users?access_token=[APP_ACCESS_TOKEN]
```